# NextJs 13, get params from the URL in the layout.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For Next.js 13, they have introduced the app route using server components. I would like to retrieve the parameters from the URL as shown below:

`app/shop/[tag]/[item]/layout.js    /shop/1/2   { tag: '1', item: '2' }`

If I access page.js at the same level as layout.js, then layout.js can retrieve the parameters as follows.

```
export default function ShopLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: {
    tag: string
    item: string
  }
}) {
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  return <section>{children}</section>
}
```

However, if I placed the layout.js in the same level as app/shop, is it possible for me to also obtain the params? it seems I can not obtain the params.

---

Comment: I think I have found a workaround, that could help you: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1838747113 `const currentPage = children.props.childProp.segment; // <--`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a route `shop/[tag]/[item]`, then:

- `app/layout.js` wont be able to access both `tag` and `item`
- `app/shop/layout.js` wont be able to access both `tag` and `item`
- `app/shop/[tag]/layout.js` can access `tag` but not `item`
- `app/shop/[tag]/[item]/layout.js` can access both `tag` and `item`

So depending on where you place the `layout.js`, the access to `tag` and `item` will be different.

---

You can instead do something called [Optional Catch-all Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments)

For example, `app/shop/[[...slug]]/page.js` will match:

- `/shop`
- `/shop/1`
- `/shop/1/2`
- and so on

If you try to visit `/shop/1/2`, the `params` will be:

```
{ slug: ['1', '2'] }
```

Comment: how about the layout for the Optional Catch-all Segments? Is it fine to catch the slug too?

Comment: @VincentChan Yes, it will catch the slug. If its fine, please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: I see, thanks. May I know if is there any way to opt out of the particular layout?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235764/nextjs-13-how-to-opt-out-the-layout

Comment: @VincentChan If my answer answers your question, can you kindly upvote and accept my answer? I'll meanwhile, take a look at your new question